Split tiles with geom_tile (ggplot) with fill gradient
I am trying to replicate this kind of plot using ggplot.

To achieve that, I need to have only the diagonal tiles as triangles. I have a single data frame with two batches of data.
    df$Triangle == "Individual" (top triangle)
    df$Triangle == "Population" (bottom triangle)

Here is my current code:
# Defines colour palette and breaks ~
color_palette <- c("#001260", "#EAEDE9", "#601200")
nHalf <- 4
Min <- -.1
Max <- .1
Thresh <- 0

rc1 <- colorRampPalette(colors = color_palette[1:2], space = "Lab")(nHalf)
rc2 <- colorRampPalette(colors = color_palette[2:3], space = "Lab")(nHalf)
rampcols <- c(rc1, rc2)
rampcols[c(nHalf, nHalf+1)] <- rgb(t(col2rgb(color_palette[2])), maxColorValue = 256) 

rb1 <- seq(Min, Thresh, length.out = nHalf + 1)
rb2 <- seq(Thresh, Max, length.out = nHalf + 1)[-1]
rampbreaks <- c(rb1, rb2)


# Creates Ind_PLot ~
    Ind_Plot <-
      ggplot() + 
      geom_tile(data = subset(fulldf, Triangle == "Individual"), aes(Ind_1, Ind_2, fill = as.numeric(Value)), colour = "#000000")  +
      scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rampcols, breaks = rampbreaks, limits = c(-.1, .1)) +
      facet_grid(K ~ CHRType, scales = "free", space = "free") +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff"),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"),
            legend.position = "right",
            legend.key = element_blank(),
            legend.background = element_blank(),
            legend.margin = margin(t = 0, b = 0, r = 15, l = 15),
            legend.box = "vertical",
            legend.box.margin = margin(t = 20, b = 30, r = 0, l = 0),
            axis.title = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(color = "#000000", size = 16, face = "bold", angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
            axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#000000", size = 16, face = "bold"),
            axis.ticks = element_line(color = "#000000", linewidth = .3),
            strip.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size = 24, face = "bold", family = "Optima"),
            strip.background = element_rect(colour = "#000000", fill = "#d6d6d6", linewidth = .3),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "#000000", linewidth = .3)) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "", title.theme = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
                                 label.theme = element_text(size = 15), reverse = TRUE))


# Creates Mean_PLot ~
    Mean_Plot <-
      ggplot() + 
      geom_tile(data = subset(fulldf, Triangle == "Population"), aes(Population_1, Population_2, fill = as.numeric(Value)), colour = "#000000")  +
      scale_x_discrete(limits = rev, expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_y_discrete(limits = rev, expand = c(0, 0)) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rampcols, breaks = rampbreaks, limits = c(-.1, .1)) +
      facet_grid(K ~ CHRType, scales = "free", space = "free") +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#ffffff"),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"),
            legend.position = "right",
            legend.key = element_blank(),
            legend.background = element_blank(),
            legend.margin = margin(t = 0, b = 0, r = 15, l = 15),
            legend.box = "vertical",
            legend.box.margin = margin(t = 20, b = 30, r = 0, l = 0),
            axis.title = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(color = "#000000", size = 16, face = "bold", angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
            axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#000000", size = 16, face = "bold"),
            axis.ticks = element_line(color = "#000000", linewidth = .3),
            strip.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size = 24, face = "bold", family = "Optima"),
            strip.background = element_rect(colour = "#000000", fill = "#d6d6d6", linewidth = .3),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "#000000", linewidth = .3)) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "", title.theme = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
                                 label.theme = element_text(size = 15), reverse = TRUE))

You can download a dummy fulldf from here.
Does anyone know if it is possible to replicate this behaviour in ggplot?
Many thanks in advance, George.

Could you provide some example data that the others can use to try to help you?

Thanks for your suggestion. A link for a dummy data has been added.

I have the data now. However, when I run your code, there are other objects such as rampcols and rampbreaks that are not defined. Please, be sure to share a reproducible example, you can use the {reprex} package which checks the reproducibility of the output provided.

Sorry -- done! @JosepPueyo :)

Here is one possible option which uses geom_polygon to draw the triangles for the diagonal. Also note that I use a geom_point to draw the individual plot:
fulldf <- readr::read_tsv(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/g-pacheco/TEMP/1b93c734472fb5282ba6a1ea7fff57fb5b3699d6/fulldf.csv"
)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

dat_ind <- fulldf |>
  filter(Triangle == "Individual") |>
  mutate(
    x = as.numeric(factor(Population_1)),
    y = as.numeric(factor(Population_2))
  ) |>
  split(~ Population_1 + Population_2, drop = TRUE) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    x |>
      mutate(
        x = x + .5 * scales::rescale(
          as.numeric(factor(Ind_1)),
          to = c(-1, 1)
        ),
        y = y + .5 * scales::rescale(
          as.numeric(factor(Ind_2)),
          to = c(-1, 1)
        )
      )
  }) |>
  bind_rows()

make_polygon1 <- function(x, y, Value) {
  data.frame(
    x = x + .5 * c(1, 1, -1),
    y = y + .5 * c(1, -1, -1),
    Value = Value
  )
}

dat_pop_diag <- fulldf |>
  filter(Triangle == "Population", Population_1 == Population_2) |>
  mutate(
    x = as.numeric(factor(Population_2)),
    y = as.numeric(factor(Population_1))
  ) |>
  reframe(
    make_polygon1(x, y, Value),
    .by = c(Population_1, Population_2, CHRType, K)
  )

make_polygon2 <- function(x, y) {
  data.frame(
    x = x - .5 * c(1, 1, -1),
    y = y - .5 * c(1, -1, -1)
  )
}

dat_ind_diag <- fulldf |>
  filter(Triangle == "Population", Population_1 == Population_2) |>
  mutate(
    x = as.numeric(factor(Population_1)),
    y = as.numeric(factor(Population_2))
  ) |>
  reframe(
    make_polygon2(x, y),
    .by = c(Population_1, Population_2, CHRType, K)
  )

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(
    data = dat_pop_diag,
    aes(x, y, group = interaction(Population_1, Population_2), fill = Value),
    colour = "#000000",
    linewidth = .1,
  ) +
  geom_tile(
    data = filter(fulldf, Triangle == "Population", Population_1 != Population_2),
    aes(
      Population_2,
      Population_1,
      fill = Value
    ), colour = "#000000"
  ) +
  # Individual plot
  geom_point(
    data = dat_ind,
    aes(
      x, y,
      color = Value
    ),
    size = .25,
    shape = 15
  ) +
  # Upper Triangle Grid
  geom_tile(
    data = filter(fulldf, Triangle == "Population", Population_1 != Population_2),
    aes(Population_1, Population_2), fill = NA, colour = "#000000"
  ) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = dat_ind_diag,
    aes(x, y, group = interaction(Population_1, Population_2)),
    colour = alpha("#000000", .7),
    linewidth = .1,
    fill = NA
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = rampcols, breaks = rampbreaks, limits = c(-.1, .1),
    aesthetics = c("color", "fill"),
    guide = guide_legend(
      title = "", title.theme = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
      label.theme = element_text(size = 15), reverse = TRUE
    ),
    na.value = "transparent"
  ) +
  facet_grid(K ~ CHRType, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)
  )


